# Taking a front camera shot from a backgrounded app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, camera

I'm trying to capture a front camera shot when my app is in the background.
`captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:` works fine when the app is in the foreground, but it fails when the app is in the background. What can I do?

Comment: Speaking as a user, I don't think I want a backgrounded app to be able to take pictures. I'd be surprised if Apple felt differently.

Comment: backgrounded means grounded... Then no use at all. Except run a backgrond thread even for a certain time only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not allowed in iOS. Check the apple guidelines [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html). Specifically the section "Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks".

You can see from this section that using the camera is not supported in the background state.

**Special tasks that are supported in the background include:**

- audio processing/playing
- location services
- voip
- newstand-content
- external-accessory
- bluetooth.